# How to split a string into substrings?

Tags: powershell

I have a file named collection.xml which contains a list of movies in my Easter movie collection shown below.  Once I get these I'm trying to use Split to split the files on the strings "Movies/" and .  This would result in movie names like:

The Easter Bunny is Coming to Town (2006).mp4

I've been trying various permutations of Split() and the -split modifier.  How can I split the output below to get just the movie names as shown above?

```
Get-Content .\collection.xml | Select-String Path

      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Here Comes Peter Cottontail (1971).mp4</Path>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Here Comes Peter Cottontail - The Movie (2005).mp4</Path>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Movies/The Easter Bunny is Coming to Town (2006).mp4</Path>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Its The Easter Beagle Charlie Brown (2008).mp4</Path>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Hop (2011).mp4</Path>
      <Path>/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Peter Rabbit (2018).mp4</Path>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward if you treat this as an XML file full of filenames as you can do this in a single line; I've broken into a multiple for ease of reading:

**Option 1:**

```
([xml](get-content temp.txt)).SelectNodes("//Path") | foreach-object {
    [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.'#text') 
}
```

This effectively:

1. Reads the file in as XML
2. Selects all the "Path" nodes in the file - you may need to adjust this to better match your actual XML file. This is a straightforward XPath.
3. For each node found, call the .NET native method over the text part of the node to extract the filename

**Option 2:**

Pretty much the same, but using more native XML cmdlets, which may make easier reading:

```
(select-xml -xpath '//Path' -path .\temp.txt).Node | foreach-object { 
    [io.path]::GetFilenameWithoutExtension($_.'#text') 
}
```

Again, tune the XPath to suit your XML file.

There's various ways to structure both of these for your taste (and exact XML format) by moving the ".Node" and ".'#text'" selectors inside (or outside) the foreach; for example, we can remove the brackets around `select-xml` in the line above by shifting Node within the foreach:

```
select-xml -xpath '//Path' -path .\temp.txt | foreach-object { 
    [io.path]::GetFilenameWithoutExtension($_.Node.'#text') 
}
```

...and variations on a theme. Your XML file structure can have a bearing on this; anything else is personal preference and readability.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect!  I should have use PowerShell's XML tools for this.  Tell me, what is the '#text' parameter?

Comment: An XML file is just a bunch of nodes. The text between opening and closing tags in XML is a node itself which (in the case of Powershell) it assigns to the `#text` pseudo-node. So if you just do (say) `(select-xml -xpath '//Path' -path file).Node` you'll see the output is the contents of all your Path nodes in a column with a header (i.e., property) of `#text`. If you do `(select-xml -xpath '//Path' -path file).Node | get-member`, this shows that the `#text` property has a type of `XmlElement`. Accessing `#text` as property in PS then just gives the text value (via implicit `ToString()`).

Comment: I should add, `#text` is in single quotes in the main answer because Powershell properties can't (usually) start with special chars. So it needs the single quotes to escape the propety name (and not throw a syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what your full .xml file looks like, I made this with just the info you gave, and some simple regex.

I'm making a couple assumptions here

1. Your file path always ends in "Movies"
2. You don't want the file type at the end of the string

```
$banana = Get-Content C:\Temp\collection.xml | Select-String Path

foreach($line in $banana)
{
    #load the line as an xml object, expand the path property, and replace the characters we don't want.
    ([xml]$line).Path -replace "^\/.+Movies\/|\..+$"

}
```

Those hieroglyphics after the `-replace` mean this

`^` : Start of the line

`\/` : Literal `/` character

`.` : Any character (except line terminators)

`+` : At least one, but up to infinite

`Movies` : The literal string "Movies"

`\/` : Literal `/` character

`|` : Or

`\.` : Literal `.` (period) character

`.+` : `.` and `+` combined, meaning any character least once, but up to infinite

`$` : End of the line